# On sever subpages not working in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have uploaded React JS project on the server and the home page is working but other pages showing 500 Internal Server errors and also the page is loading.
Anyone has the solution for that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/alexsasharegan/173878f9d67055bfef63449fa7136042. If server on Apache try creating that .htaccess.